# Trying to position a DIV at center of browser viewport window using jquery animate function

Tags: jquery

I was trying to position a DIV at center of browser viewport window using jquery animate function.

The problem is that DIV is not centering at the center rather div is position is close to center.

So my concern is what I am missing for which div is not positioning at the center of browser viewport window uisng jquery animate function.

Here is my full code. so please see my code and guide me what I am missing.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $("form #UPSContainer").each(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });

            $('form').append('<div id="UPSContainer" class="hidden" style="background:red;display:none;position:absolute"></div>');
            if ($("#UPSContainer").exists() == true) {
                $("#UPSContainer").css({ height: 0, width: 0, display: 'block' });

                var xleft = ($(window).width() - $("#UPSContainer").width());
                var xtop = ($(window).height() - $("#UPSContainer").height());

                $("#UPSContainer").css({ left: xleft, top: xtop });
                $("#UPSContainer").animate({
                    left: (($(window).width() - $("#UPSContainer").width()) / 2) + 'px',
                    top: (($(window).height() - $("#UPSContainer").height()) / 2) + 'px',
                    height: 100 + 'px', width: 100 + 'px'
                }, 200,
                function () {
                    //$("#feed_dialog").removeClass("BusyStyles").find('#acloginpod').fadeIn(2000);
                });

            }
            return false;
        });


        jQuery.fn.exists = function () { return this.length > 0; }
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" id="ctl00">
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Fly DIV" id="Button1" style="display:block" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### EDIT

Here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/p4e4psg4/). I was trying to make appear my div from bottom right corner. Initially my div will have zero in size and when it will move to center then its size will increase.

I do not know why the div is not getting position at the center of the screen.

### EDIT

I user your code and modify bit for getting my out put. here is my full code and [js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/3jrt48s4/)

### html

```
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Fly DIV" id="Button1" class="toggleUPSContainer" />

<div class="UPS_rate_time">
<div class="information">UPS Time and Transit Details</div>
<div class="national">
<span style="color:White;font-weight:bold;">National</span>
<ul>
<li>1 Business Day</li>
<li>Delivery by 9:00 a.m</li>
<li>UPS Express Plus</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>1 Business Day</li>
<li>Delivery by 9:00 a.m</li>
<li>UPS Express Plus</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>1 Business Day</li>
<li>Delivery by 9:00 a.m</li>
<li>UPS Express Plus</li>
</ul>


</div>

<div class="international">
<span style="color:White;font-weight:bold;">International</span>

<ul>
<li>1 Business Day</li>
<li>Delivery by 9:00 a.m</li>
<li>UPS Express Plus</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>1 Business Day</li>
<li>Delivery by 9:00 a.m</li>
<li>UPS Express Plus</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>1 Business Day</li>
<li>Delivery by 9:00 a.m</li>
<li>UPS Express Plus</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="tntclose">Close</div>
</div>
```

### css

```
 #UPSContainer{
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        background:white;
        height:0;
        width:0;
        position:fixed;
        border: thin solid black;
    }  

    /* TNT Style Start*/
        .UPS_rate_time
        {
            border: thin solid black;
            width: 600px;
            height: auto!;
            min-height: 360px;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: none;
        }

        .information
        {
            background: #3ab54b;
            width: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            color:White;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:26px;
        }

        .national, .international
        {
            width: 49%;
            float: left;
            height: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left:3px;
        }

        .national
        {
        }

        .international
        {
            margin-left: 1%;
        }

        .national span, .international span
        {
            display: block;
            background: #3ab54b;
            padding: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .national ul
        {
            margin: 9px 59px -8px -31px;
            height: auto;
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-bottom: thin solid #ccc;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .national ul li
        {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            list-style: none;
            width: 30%;
            text-align: left;
            margin: 1px;
            border-right: thin solid #ccc;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        .national ul:nth-child(odd)
        {
            background: #eee;
        }

        .international ul
        {
            margin: 9px 59px -8px -31px;
            height: auto;
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-bottom: thin solid #ccc;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .international ul li
        {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            list-style: none;
            width: 30%;
            text-align: left;
            margin: 1px;
            border-right: thin solid #ccc;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        .international ul:nth-child(odd)
        {
            background: #eee;
        }

        .tntclose
        {
            border: thin solid #3ab54b;
            float: right;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #3ab54b;
            color:White;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
```

### js code

```
var flag = false;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $els = [];
            var data = {
                "UPSContainer": {
                    "height": 360,
                    "width": 600
                },
                "isAnimating": false
            };
            $els.window = $(window);
            $els.body = $('body');
            $els.toggleUPSButtons = $('.toggleUPSContainer');
            $els.tntclose = $('.tntclose');

            function addUPSOverlay() {
                $els.body.append('<div id="UPSContainer"></div>');
                $els.UPSContainer = $('#UPSContainer');
                $els.UPSContainer.css({ opacity: 0 });
            }

            function getNewWindowCorner() {
                data.windowWidth = parseInt($els.window.width());
                data.windowHeight = parseInt($els.window.height());
                if ($els.UPSContainer.is(':hidden')) {
                    $els.UPSContainer.css({
                        top: data.windowHeight + 'px',
                        left: data.windowWidth + 'px'
                    });
                } else {
                    $els.UPSContainer.css({
                        left: ((data.windowWidth - data.UPSContainer.width) / 2) + 'px',
                        top: ((data.windowHeight - data.UPSContainer.height) / 2) + 'px'
                    });
                }
            }

            function containerOpenComplete() {
                // do what you want here when opening complete
            }

            function containerCloseComplete() {
                // do what you want here when closing complete
            }

            function toggleUPSOverlay(e) {
                //e.preventDefault();
                if (!data.isAnimating) {
                    if ($els.UPSContainer.is(':hidden')) { // currently closed so open
                        data.isAnimating = true;
                        $els.UPSContainer.show();
                        $els.UPSContainer.animate({
                            left: ((data.windowWidth - data.UPSContainer.width) / 2) + 'px',
                            top: ((data.windowHeight - data.UPSContainer.height) / 2) + 'px',
                            height: data.UPSContainer.height + 'px',
                            width: data.UPSContainer.width + 'px',
                            opacity: 1
                        },
                        { duration: 800, queue: false, easing: 'easeOutQuart',
                            step: function (now, tween) {
                                if (tween.prop === 'width') {
                                    if (now >= 250) {
                                        //console.log('Width reached 50%');
                                        if (!flag) {
                                            flag = true;
                                            //$("body").append('Width reached 50%' + now);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            complete: function () {
                                $els.UPSContainer.append($('.UPS_rate_time').fadeIn(300));
                                data.isAnimating = false;
                            }
                        });
                    } else { // currently open so close
                        data.isAnimating = true;
                        $els.UPSContainer.animate({
                            left: data.windowWidth + 'px',
                            top: data.windowHeight + 'px',
                            height: 0 + 'px',
                            width: 0 + 'px',
                            opacity: 0
                        },
                        { duration: 800, queue: false, easing: 'easeOutQuart',
                            complete: function () {
                                $('.UPS_rate_time').fadeOut('slow').css({ display: 'none' });
                                $els.UPSContainer.hide();
                                data.isAnimating = false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            function attachEvents() {
                $els.window.bind('resize', getNewWindowCorner);
                $els.toggleUPSButtons.bind('click', toggleUPSOverlay);
                $els.tntclose.bind('click', toggleUPSOverlay);
            }

            function initialize() {
                addUPSOverlay();
                getNewWindowCorner();
                attachEvents();
                toggleUPSOverlay();
            }

            initialize();
        });
```

Comment: Remove position absolute from your css

Comment: no your tips did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with simple CSS3.

You are currently positioning the top left corner of your element in the center of the screen. Either you can add a bunch more code to your js. Or add these 5 lines of CSS

```
#UPSContainer{
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p4e4psg4/1/)**

---

EDIT: cross browser using negative margins

An alternative is to use negative margins on the fly div. Note that this option only works if you know what the end height and width of your element is going to be (appears you're setting it in the animation anyways)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        $("form #UPSContainer").each(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        $('form').append('<div id="UPSContainer" class="hidden" style="background:red;display:none;position:absolute"></div>');
        if ($("#UPSContainer").exists() == true) {
            $("#UPSContainer").css({ height: 0, width: 0, display: 'block' });

            var xleft = ($(window).width() - $("#UPSContainer").width());
            var xtop = ($(window).height() - $("#UPSContainer").height());

            $("#UPSContainer").css({ left: xleft, top: xtop });
            $("#UPSContainer").animate({
                left: (($(window).width() - $("#UPSContainer").width()) / 2) + 'px',
                top: (($(window).height() - $("#UPSContainer").height()) / 2) + 'px',
                height: 100 + 'px', 
                width: 100 + 'px',
                marginLeft: '-50px',
                marginTop: '-50px'
            }, 200,
            function () {
                //$("#feed_dialog").removeClass("BusyStyles").find('#acloginpod').fadeIn(2000);
            });

        }
        return false;
    });


    jQuery.fn.exists = function () { return this.length > 0; }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p4e4psg4/2/)**

---

EDIT: request for a way to toggle the box open and closed

I have **significantly** changed your code. I have done this as there was going to be a whole lot of repeated steps if i were to just use the code you supplied. The caching of jQuery DOM searching, data attributes to store global variables, updates to allow for window resizing, single DOM insertion of elements, were all done in an attempt to write speedy jQuery code.

You can now have multiple buttons to open/close the overlay.. just give them the class `toggleUPSContainer`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $els = [];
    var data = {
        "UPSContainer": {
            "height" : 100,
            "width" : 100
        },
        "isAnimating" : false
    };
    $els.window = $(window);
    $els.form = $('#ctl00');
    $els.toggleUPSButtons = $('.toggleUPSContainer');

    function addUPSOverlay(){
        $els.form.append('<div id="UPSContainer"></div>');
        $els.UPSContainer = $('#UPSContainer');
    }

    function getNewWindowCorner(){
        data.windowWidth = parseInt($els.window.width());
        data.windowHeight = parseInt($els.window.height());
        if($els.UPSContainer.is(':hidden')){
            $els.UPSContainer.css({
                top: data.windowHeight + 'px',
                left: data.windowWidth + 'px'
            });
        }else{
            $els.UPSContainer.css({
                left: ((data.windowWidth - data.UPSContainer.width) / 2) + 'px',
                top: ((data.windowHeight - data.UPSContainer.height) / 2) + 'px'
            });
        }
    }

    function containerOpenComplete(){
        // do what you want here when opening complete
    }

    function containerCloseComplete(){
        // do what you want here when closing complete
    }

    function toggleUPSOverlay(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!data.isAnimating){
            if($els.UPSContainer.is(':hidden')){ // currently closed so open
                $els.UPSContainer.show();
                $els.UPSContainer.animate({
                        left: ((data.windowWidth - data.UPSContainer.width) / 2) + 'px',
                        top: ((data.windowHeight - data.UPSContainer.height) / 2) + 'px',
                        height: data.UPSContainer.height + 'px', 
                        width: data.UPSContainer.width + 'px'
                }, 200, function(){
                    containerOpenComplete();
                });
            }else{ // currently open so close
                $els.UPSContainer.animate({
                        left: data.windowWidth + 'px',
                        top: data.windowHeight + 'px',
                        height: 0 + 'px', 
                        width: 0 + 'px'
                    }, 200,
                    function () {
                        $els.UPSContainer.hide();
                        containerCloseComplete();
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    function attachEvents(){
        $els.window.on('resize', getNewWindowCorner);
        $els.toggleUPSButtons.on('click', toggleUPSOverlay);
    }

    function initialize(){
        addUPSOverlay();
        getNewWindowCorner();
        attachEvents();
    }

    initialize();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p4e4psg4/5/)**

Comment: i want the solution which will be independent of browser version and here u gave css 3 which does not support by old browser.

Comment: @Thomas, ah ok, that wasnt specified in your question. Is the size of the Fly div always going to be the same?

Comment: can u plzz tell me how to have a reverse effect like toggle.i want now when i will click on the div then div will flyout to center of the screen from bottom-right side and when i will click on it again then div will move to bottom-right side and height & width will decrease to zero? just edit ur script and guide me how to have toggle effect? thanks

Comment: @Thomas, updated with a crossbrowser solution using negative margin. As for toggling the window open and closed.. i would be doing the entire script differently.. let me have a look at it

Comment: thanks for 2nd jsfiddle link. if possible please edit ur script as a result when user click on button the div will appear at center from bottom-right corner and when again click if div is visible then div will move to bottom-right corner from center and  same way div size will be zero gradually. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Thomas, 3rd Edit is up. I couldnt leave the code in the way it was, apologies for changing it so much, i hope it still makes sense, but it was done to the standard that i was taught to write code to.

Comment: thanks for your 3rd edit. can we add callback which will alert a message like div is UP and down too. i mean when user click on button then div will appear and a message will show like "div up" and when user click on button then div goes back to bottom-right corner and a message will show like "div down". it will be great if u add few code to existing one for this callback facility.

Comment: @Thomas, FINAL edits made (updated edit 3), there are now 2 function `containerOpenComplete` and `containerCloseComplete` that you can add whatever you want to

Comment: in your 2nd sample you work with marginLeft & marginTop property but in ur final version u did not use those property....why. please tell me the reason?

Comment: can you please see my js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/6o1wv3yt/ because i am not being able to generate reverse effect....what i am missing in my code. thanks

Comment: :how data.windowWidth comes from? i have seen u have one object literal called var data{} and it has some property but it has no property called windowWidth. will u plzz explain about from where this windowWidth  comes ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65657/discussion-between-haxxxton-and-thomas).